# ReactJS - How to style React Calendar

Tags: javascript, reactjs, calendar

I've just installed the react-calendar package using

```
npm install react-calendar
```

but I have no idea how to style it, or to give it some color. The instructions in [react-calendar - npm](https://www.npmjs.com/package/react-calendar) do not provide any information about that. I was wondering if anyone that has used this package could help me here. 
This is the code I have:

```
import React, {Component} from 'react'
import Calendar from 'react-calendar'
export default class EventModifier extends Component {

    state = {
        date: new Date(2018, 6, 1)
    }

render(){
let calendar = <Calendar onChange={this.onChange} value={this.state.date} onClickDay={(value) => alert("day" + value + "clicked")}/>
return(
<div>
{calendar}
</div>
)
}
}
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Use **className** prop that will be added along with "react-calendar" to the main React-Calendar  element. and it can be used to style the calendar as you want

```
<Calendar className={['c1','c2']}/>
```

Answer (score 10):

Go to node_modules / react-calender / dist / Calender.css, copy all the content in your own css or scss file and there you will have all the default styles and you can change only the ones you want.

To this date the file looks something like this:

```css
.react-calendar {
  width: 350px;
  max-width: 100%;
  background: white;
  border: 1px solid #a0a096;
  font-family: Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif;
  line-height: 1.125em;
}
.react-calendar--doubleView {
  width: 700px;
}
.react-calendar--doubleView .react-calendar__viewContainer {
  display: flex;
  margin: -0.5em;
}
.react-calendar--doubleView .react-calendar__viewContainer > * {
  width: 50%;
  margin: 0.5em;
}
.react-calendar,
.react-calendar *,
.react-calendar *:before,
.react-calendar *:after {
  -moz-box-sizing: border-box;
  -webkit-box-sizing: border-box;
  box-sizing: border-box;
}
.react-calendar button {
  margin: 0;
  border: 0;
  outline: none;
}
.react-calendar button:enabled:hover {
  cursor: pointer;
}
.react-calendar__navigation {
  height: 44px;
  margin-bottom: 1em;
}
.react-calendar__navigation button {
  min-width: 44px;
  background: none;
}
.react-calendar__navigation button:enabled:hover,
.react-calendar__navigation button:enabled:focus {
  background-color: #e6e6e6;
}
.react-calendar__navigation button[disabled] {
  background-color: #f0f0f0;
}
.react-calendar__month-view__weekdays {
  text-align: center;
  text-transform: uppercase;
  font-weight: bold;
  font-size: 0.75em;
}
.react-calendar__month-view__weekdays__weekday {
  padding: 0.5em;
}
.react-calendar__month-view__weekNumbers {
  font-weight: bold;
}
.react-calendar__month-view__weekNumbers .react-calendar__tile {
  display: flex;
  align-items: center;
  justify-content: center;
  font-size: 0.75em;
  padding: calc(0.75em / 0.75) calc(0.5em / 0.75);
}
.react-calendar__month-view__days__day--weekend {
  color: #d10000;
}
.react-calendar__month-view__days__day--neighboringMonth {
  color: #757575;
}
.react-calendar__year-view .react-calendar__tile,
.react-calendar__decade-view .react-calendar__tile,
.react-calendar__century-view .react-calendar__tile {
  padding: 2em 0.5em;
}
.react-calendar__tile {
  max-width: 100%;
  text-align: center;
  padding: 0.75em 0.5em;
  background: none;
}
.react-calendar__tile:disabled {
  background-color: #f0f0f0;
}
.react-calendar__tile:enabled:hover,
.react-calendar__tile:enabled:focus {
  background-color: #e6e6e6;
}
.react-calendar__tile--now {
  background: #ffff76;
}
.react-calendar__tile--now:enabled:hover,
.react-calendar__tile--now:enabled:focus {
  background: #ffffa9;
}
.react-calendar__tile--hasActive {
  background: #76baff;
}
.react-calendar__tile--hasActive:enabled:hover,
.react-calendar__tile--hasActive:enabled:focus {
  background: #a9d4ff;
}
.react-calendar__tile--active {
  background: #006edc;
  color: white;
}
.react-calendar__tile--active:enabled:hover,
.react-calendar__tile--active:enabled:focus {
  background: #1087ff;
}
.react-calendar--selectRange .react-calendar__tile--hover {
  background-color: #e6e6e6;
}
```

Answer (score 4):

import './Calender.scss';

```
          <Calendar  onChange={onChange}  value={state.date} className="react-calendar" />
```

**Calender.scss**

.react-calendar {
    width: 600px;

```
.react-calendar__navigation {
    .react-calendar__navigation__arrow {
        display: none;
    }

    .react-calendar__navigation__label {
        font-size: 32px;
    }
}

.react-calendar__tile {
    height: 70px;
}

.react-calendar__month-view__weekdays__weekday {
    font-size: 16px;
    color: rgb(15, 70, 15);
}

.react-calendar__tile--active {
    background: #e70220;
    color: white;
}

.react-calendar__tile--active:enabled:hover,
.react-calendar__tile--active:enabled:focus {
    background: #e70220;
}

.react-calendar__tile,
.react-calendar__month-view__days__day {
    font-size: 18px;
}
```

}